# Adjusting JMS settings for HP Service Test from cmdline

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

We're using HP Service Test 11.50 to run unittests on a Jenkins Buildserver. We'd like to run parallel builds, which means that we must be able to specify a port before executing these tests. This way we can ensure that all tests are isolated from eachother. By executing a couple of queries on the test.db we've been able to change the testSettings, but these changes aren't picked up. Only after (re)compiling the test within the HP Service Test GUI the changes are recognized and used.

Is there a way to do this compilation from commandline? Or is there another way to make this possible? And what does "compile" actually do? Which files are touched?

The wrong answer is to use input variables, because these are not yet evaluated when creating these JMS connections.

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution requires .NET SDK 4.0 installed on your machine, in this case version 4.0.30319

The test contains a `Main.cs`, which has a method called `InitJMSEnv()` which looks something like this:

```
public static void InitJMSEnv()
{
    if(!JmsInitialized)
    {
        JMSGlobalProperties props = new JMSGlobalProperties
        {
            connections_per_process = @"1",
            msg_timeout = @"1",
            user_defined_timeout = @"20",
            jndi_provider_url = @"",
            jndi_initial_context_factory = @"com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory",
            jms_connection_factory = @"",
            jms_security_principal = @"",
            jms_security_credentials = @"",
            set_corba_orb = @"",
            auto_generate_selector = @"0",
            enable_TIBCO_SSL_JNDI_lookup = @""
        };
        JMSTransportWrapper.InitJMSProperties(props);
        JmsInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

With regular expressions you can fill/adjust the required fields, such as `jms_security_principal` and `jms_security_credentials`.

Now you can rebuild the project like:

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>msbuild C:\path\to\MyTest.csproj /t:rebuild`

The result: a test which is prepared for this environment and ready to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can link (data drive) the needed property to an excel file (use the data-driving mechanism).
The excel file can be updated from outside the test. On the next test's run, the updated data from the excel file will be executed.

Regarding the compilation, in general the compilation stage generates a C# code from the test's model and builds it to a binary which is used during the test's execution

Hope this helps,

Yossi

Comment: According to one of my co-workers using Excel is comparable to using input parameters. The JNDI/JMS settings are part of the "Start"-phase, specified on the first tab. You could manipulate it by including a script, but we want to keep the work for testers as simple as possible. Their work is to write tests, it is up to us to make it environment independent somehow.